# value of char* changed after ' __android_log_write'

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

i want to call MD5 function more than one time and return the result with blow code.

```
 char *finalenc= (char*)malloc(32);
    finalenc = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < md5repeatTime; ++i) {
            if (i == 0)
                finalenc = md5(env, chtime, 0);
            else {
                finalenc = md5(env, finalenc, 0);
            }
        }
      __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "releasetimefortest", finalenc);
```

i have two problem:

1. when i Log the result the "finalenc" value is lost and change to unknow value.
2. when i call this part of code more than one time, i got this error:

   > libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000006df

**Modified:**

```
char *md5(JNIEnv *env, char *cstr, int mode) {
MD5_CTX context = {0};
MD5Init(&context);

MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char *) cstr, strlen(cstr));
unsigned char dest[16] = {0};
MD5Final(dest, &context);
char mdString[33];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)dest[i]);
    }
return mdString;
 }
```

Comment: `finalenc = "";` you are re-assigning the `finalenc` pointer, you are not modifying the pointed value, Same when you do `finalenc = md5(...)`.

Comment: what md5 function?

Comment: @Holt 
the line `finalenc = "";` is not important and i can remove that,`finalenc = md5(...)` this is work fine and i got the result but my problem appear at the last line inline 'android_log' that modify `finalenc` value.

Comment: @HassanYousefzadeh You cannot return array of character like that... `finalenc` will point to some memory into `md5`'s local scope, which is not available after `md5`.

Comment: @Holt So .What can i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**finally i find the solution:**
md5 fuction:

```
char *md5(JNIEnv *env, char *cstr,char mdString[65]) {
    MD5_CTX context = {0};
    MD5Init(&context);

    MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char *) cstr, strlen(cstr));
    unsigned char dest[16] = {0};
    MD5Final(dest, &context);
//    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, data, cstr);
//    char mdString[33];

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)dest[i]);
        }
    return mdString;
}
```

**and for call that function**

```
char mdString[65]={0};
        if (md5enable == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < md5repeatTime; ++i) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    md5(env, chtime, mdString);
                }
                else {
                     md5(env, mdString,mdString);
                }
            }


        }
```